# Почему неверно выводит таблицу двойственного симплекс метода?

Tags: java

Неправильно выводит таблицу двойственного симплекс метода, я думаю она неправильно считает дельту, ну то что я в начале неправильно дельту ввожу. В общем правильно решает прямую, но неправильно двойственную вот вывод:

```
**Enter the number of variables:
2
Enter the number of constraints:
3
Enter the coefficients of the objective function:
20 40
Enter the coefficients of the constraint matrix:
3 6 2 8 4 7
Enter the constraint constants:
200 350 150
Enter true to maximize or false to minimize:
true
Прямой симплекс метод: 
          A1      A2      A3      A4      A5      A0
x3       3,00    6,00    1,00    0,00    0,00  200,00 
x4       2,00    8,00    0,00    1,00    0,00  350,00 
x5       4,00    7,00    0,00    0,00    1,00  150,00 
△j      20,00   40,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00 
Optimal value = -0.0
          A1      A2      A3      A4      A5      A0
x3      -0,43    0,00    1,00    0,00   -0,86   71,43 
x4      -2,57    0,00    0,00    1,00   -1,14  178,57 
x2       0,57    1,00    0,00    0,00    0,14   21,43 
△j      -2,86    0,00    0,00    0,00   -5,71 -857,14 
Optimal value = 857.1428571428571
x2 = 21.428571428571427
Primal Simplex Tables:
          A1      A2      A3      A4      A5      A0
x3      -0,43    0,00    1,00    0,00   -0,86   71,43 
x4      -2,57    0,00    0,00    1,00   -1,14  178,57 
x2       0,57    1,00    0,00    0,00    0,14   21,43 
△j      -2,86    0,00    0,00    0,00   -5,71 -857,14 
Optimal value = 857.1428571428571
x2 = 21.428571428571427
Двойственный симплекс метод: 
          A1      A2      A3      A4      A5      A6      A7      A0
x6       3,00    2,00    4,00   -1,00    0,00    1,00    0,00   20,00 
x7       6,00    8,00    7,00    0,00   -1,00    0,00    1,00   40,00 
△j     200,00  350,00  150,00    0,00    0,00 1000000,00 1000000,00    0,00 
Optimal value = 0.0
          A1      A2      A3      A4      A5      A6      A7      A0
x3       0,75    0,50    1,00   -0,25    0,00    0,25    0,00    5,00 
x7       0,75    4,50    0,00    1,75   -1,00   -1,75    1,00    5,00 
△j      87,50  275,00    0,00   37,50    0,00 999962,50 1000000,00 -750,00 
Optimal value = -750.0
x3 = 5.0
Primal Simplex Tables:
          A1      A2      A3      A4      A5      A6      A7      A0
x3       0,75    0,50    1,00   -0,25    0,00    0,25    0,00    5,00 
x7       0,75    4,50    0,00    1,75   -1,00   -1,75    1,00    5,00 
△j      87,50  275,00    0,00   37,50    0,00 999962,50 1000000,00 -750,00 
Optimal value = -750.0
x3 = 5.0**
```

Вот код класса, реализующий двойственный симплекс метод:

```
public class DualSimplexMethod {
    private double[][] dualTableau;
    private boolean dualMaximizeOrMinimize;
    private int[] dualBasis;
    private int numOfConstraints;
    private int numOfVariables;
    public DualSimplexMethod(int numOfConstraints, int numOfVariables, boolean maximizeOrMinimize) {
        this.dualMaximizeOrMinimize = !maximizeOrMinimize;
        this.numOfConstraints = numOfConstraints;
        this.numOfVariables = numOfVariables;
        this.dualTableau = new double[numOfVariables + 1][numOfConstraints + numOfVariables + numOfVariables + 1];
        dualBasis = new int[numOfVariables]; //хранение базисных переменных
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfVariables; i++)
            dualBasis[i] = numOfConstraints + numOfVariables + i;
        dualSolve(); //решение злп симплекс методом
    }
    public void initializeDualTableau(double[] objectiveFunctionCoefficients, double[][] constraintCoefficients, double[] constraintConstants) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfVariables; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfConstraints; j++) {
                dualTableau[i][j] = constraintCoefficients[i][j];
                dualTableau[numOfVariables][j] = constraintConstants[j];
            }
            dualTableau[i][numOfConstraints + i] = -1;
            dualTableau[i][numOfConstraints + numOfVariables + i] = 1;
            dualTableau[i][numOfVariables + numOfConstraints + numOfVariables] = objectiveFunctionCoefficients[i];
        }
        dualTableau[numOfVariables][numOfConstraints + numOfVariables] = 1000000;
        dualTableau[numOfVariables][numOfConstraints + numOfVariables + 1] = 1000000;
        printDualSolution();
    }
    public void dualSolve() {
        while (true) {
            int pivotColumn = 0;
            if (dualMaximizeOrMinimize) { //поиск входящего столбца на основе макс значения
                pivotColumn = findPivotColumn();
            } else {
                pivotColumn = dantzigNegative();
            }
            if (pivotColumn == -1) //Если pivotColumn равен -1, это означает, что достигнуто оптимальное решение, и цикл прерывается
                break; // optimal
            // find leaving row pivotRow
            int pivotRow = minRatioRule(pivotColumn); //для поиска исходящей строки на основе правила минимального отношения
            if (pivotRow == -1)
                throw new ArithmeticException("Linear program is unbounded");
            // pivot
            pivot(pivotRow, pivotColumn);
            // update basis
            dualBasis[pivotRow] = pivotColumn;
            printDualSolution();
        }
    }
    //проходит по столбцам таблицы симплекс-метода и находит индекс столбца с наивысшим значением в строке,
    private int findPivotColumn() {
        int pivotColumn = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= (numOfConstraints + numOfVariables); j++) {
            if (dualTableau[numOfVariables][j] > dualTableau[numOfVariables][pivotColumn]) {
                pivotColumn = j;
            }
        }
        if (dualTableau[numOfVariables][pivotColumn] <= 0) {
            return -1; // optimal
        } else {
            return pivotColumn;
        }
    }
    //  выполняет поиск пивотного столбца с отрицательным значением в последней строке таблицы и возвращает его индекс, или -1, если такого столбца нет
    private int dantzigNegative() {
        int pivotColumn = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < (numOfConstraints); j++) {
            if (dualTableau[numOfVariables][j] < dualTableau[numOfVariables][pivotColumn]) {
                pivotColumn = j;
            }
        }
        if (dualTableau[numOfVariables][pivotColumn] <= 0) {
            return -1; // optimal
        } else {
            return pivotColumn;
        }
    }
    //происходит выбор опорной строки для пересчета в методе симплекса
    private int minRatioRule(int pivotColumn) {
        int pivotRow = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfVariables; i++) {
            if (dualTableau[i][pivotColumn] <= 0)
                continue;
            else if (pivotRow == -1)
                pivotRow = i;
            else if ((dualTableau[i][numOfConstraints+ numOfVariables+ numOfVariables] / dualTableau[i][pivotColumn]) <
                    (dualTableau[pivotRow][numOfConstraints+ numOfVariables+ numOfVariables] / dualTableau[pivotRow][pivotColumn]))
                pivotRow = i;
        }
        return pivotRow;
    }
    //выполняет пересчет таблицы в методе симплекса после выбора опорной строки и столбца
    private void pivot(int pivotRow, int pivotColumn) {
        // everything but row p and column pivotColumn
        for (int i = 0; i <= numOfVariables; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= numOfConstraints
                    + numOfVariables+ numOfVariables; j++)
                if (i != pivotRow && j != pivotColumn)
                    dualTableau[i][j] -= dualTableau[pivotRow][j] * dualTableau[i][pivotColumn]
                            / dualTableau[pivotRow][pivotColumn];
        // zero out column pivotColumn
        for (int i = 0; i <= numOfVariables; i++)
            if (i != pivotRow)
                dualTableau[i][pivotColumn] = 0.0;
        // scale row p
        for (int j = 0; j <= numOfConstraints + numOfVariables + numOfVariables; j++)
            if (j != pivotColumn)
                dualTableau[pivotRow][j] /= dualTableau[pivotRow][pivotColumn];
        dualTableau[pivotRow][pivotColumn] = 1.0;
    }
    public double dualValue() {
        return dualTableau[numOfVariables][numOfConstraints
                + numOfVariables+numOfVariables];
    }
    public void printDualSolution() {
        System.out.print("          ");
        for (int j = 1; j < numOfVariables + numOfConstraints + numOfVariables + 1; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%-8s", "A" + j);
        }
        System.out.print("A0");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i <= numOfVariables; i++) {
            if (i == numOfVariables) {
                System.out.printf("%-6s", "△j ");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%-6s", "x" + (dualBasis[i] + 1));
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= numOfConstraints + numOfVariables + numOfVariables; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%7.2f ", dualTableau[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Optimal value = " + dualValue());
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfVariables; i++) {
            if (dualBasis[i] < numOfConstraints) {
                System.out.println("x" + (dualBasis[i] + 1) + " = " + dualTableau[i][numOfConstraints + numOfVariables + numOfVariables]);
            }
        }
    }
}**
```